# Turn off regions in VS2010 C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor

I want to turn off regions handling (small + and - signs in the left side, used for regions collapsing) for C/C++ files in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ Formatting -> Enable Outlining -> False

You need to reopen file for this taking effect.